# How to use onInput to take two values and create a gradient from this?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to adjust a gradient in real time by taking users' color input. I get an error whenever I adjust one value - it states that the other value is not given.

```js
 function btnGradient(input1, input2){
 btn.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right," + input1.value + ", " + input2.value + ")"; };
```

```html
<label>Background Gradient: <input type="color" onInput="btnGradient(this, input2);"></label>

<label>Background Gradient: <input type="color" onInput="btnGradient(input1, this);"></label>
```

Any ideas on how I would go about performing this? Thank you.

Comment: I see errors: `input1 is not defined` and/or `input2 is not defined`. Where do you define them so you can pass them to `btnGradient()`?

Comment: what is `input2` and `input1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.
HTML:

```
<label>Background Gradient: <input id="gradient1" type="color" onInput="btnGradient();"></label>
<label>Background Gradient: <input id="gradient2" type="color" onInput="btnGradient();"></label>
```

JavaScript:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("gradient1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("gradient2");

function btnGradient() {
    btn.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right," + input1.value + ", " + input2.value + ")";
}
```

UPD: It looks like you haven't initialized variables input1, input2. So you don't have links to those field.

Comment: Seems to be an extra `}` in `btnGradient()`. Also might be helpful to explain what was wrong and how you solved it.

Comment: @showdev Yep, haven't noticed extra bracket. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just another way how to do it:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
document.querySelectorAll('#color1, #color2').forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('change', () => btn.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, ${document.getElementById('color1').value}, ${document.getElementById('color2').value})`);
}, false)
```

```html
<label>Background Gradient: <input type="color" id="color1"></label>
<label>Background Gradient: <input type="color" id="color2"></label> 
<button id="btn">Send</button>
```